# macOS inserting DNS servers which are not in DHCP response

Tags: macos, network, wifi, dns

I used Wireshark to confirm the DHCP response packet has only the IPv4 addresses which I have configured on my home router.

macOS seems to be occasionally (but didn't this time) inserting Google IPv6 addresses, preventing my PiHole from blocking things.

```
<my ipv4 DNS1>
<my ipv4 DNS2>
2001:4860:4860::8888
2001:4860:4860::8844
```

How can I prevent this?

Comment: Enabling the PiHole for IPv6 is no option?

Comment: Do you have any Google software, Chrome or other? It might be hard coded into the app, just guessing here.

Comment: @SteveChambers great guess, but no. I intentionally avoid installing anything from GOOG, even Chrome, because I don't trust them. Chrome is spyware.